# A formula that changes conditional formating based on intervals

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Say that I want an Excel table to let me know when a certain procedure is to be done on my cars. Every 100 km I need to do X, every 200 km I need to do Y and so on. I want the formula to paint certain cells red so that I know right away that a certain maintenance procedure has to get done. Is this doable?

[image: Sample]

Assume that I have two machines. One is new (amount of work hours is zero), and the other one is used (over 5000 work hours already). I want to input the amount of hours for one machine in one cell, and the formula for each time period (daily, weekly, every 6 months, etc...) to show me which maintenance procedure has to be done.

Comment: can you please post some sample data with desired output?

Comment: I just added a sample of what the table should look like. Basically the only data that the user (me or any other worker in the company) is expected to input is the amount of work hours any given machine has had.

Answer (score 2):

Assume U21 is Current time, and W21 is Criterion time e.g.
U21 = 10210  W21 =1000 10%
then you can put Your Xses on the table by simple modulo operator and If statement. 
=IF(MOD(U21;W21)=0;"X";0)
Or If You want to have say some tolerance based on rest from division 
=IF(MOD(U21;W21)<=5;"X";0)
Or if You want have tolerance bounds based on 10% Criterion 
=IF(U21-INTEEGER(U21/W21)*W21<W21*0.1;"X";"0")

Then color Your Xses by conditional formatting

Comment: I owe you a beer. This works! Thanks a lot!